# Import csv with paths to pdf files

Tags: csv, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-feeds

I have a custom content type (product) containing a title, some text and a file (a pdf file).
A lot of products have to be imported to the Drupal CMS. I discovered the plugin "Feeds" which seems to fulfill my requirements.

I managed to import a csv files containing a title and some text.

Now in my csv file I have a column containing a path to all the pdf files (like C:\mypdfs\product1.pdf). How can I manage that those pdf files are imported by Feeds? In "Mapping" configuration I'm not sure what target I have to select for those column which contains the path to a local file.

Answer (score 1):

Using Feeds Tamper module you can manipulate the value of imported data for one target. Here you can build a custom tamper ([See How](http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/how-to-create-a-custom-feeds-tamper-plugin/2011-11-18)) and use it to process the retrieved value (file path), using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to get the file from imported path and [file_save_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_save_data/7) to save a file in Drupal, getting a field object that you can attach to an entity ([this could help](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/23890/import-files-into-a-file-field-in-drupal-7)).

Comment: Sounds complicated. I hoped for an out-of-the-box-solution.